# Get the ids where it has multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

My Data is like

```
id   name     status
1    test     True
2    prod     True
3    Db       False
1    test     False
4    Staging  True
3    Db       False
2    prod     True
```

I want to group my data based on id and get the data ids which has status as True and also as False. Above data should return as:

```
id    name    Status
1     Test    True
```

Comment: I am able to apply groupby and but want to check if the id contains both the statsus True and also false in separate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use this:

```
df = df.groupby('d').filter(lambda x: any(x['status'] == True))
df = df.groupby('d').filter(lambda x: any(x['status'] == False))
```

Output:

```
   d  name status
0  1  test   True
3  1  test  False
```

And in case after apply `drop_duplicates`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['d'])
```

Comment: This Doesn't work. Drop duplicates wont check if it has both True and False

Comment: `drop_duplicates` should be used only after the first 2 lines. Have you tried them?